no puedo acceder a mi instancia de amazon lightsail
desde ayer no puedo conectarme a mi instancia debian de amazon lightsail (antes si podía), siempre me da un timeout desde putty y si hago ping desde consola, sin embargo si que puedo acceder a la instancia a través del navegador http://15.237.65.162. Tengo abiertos los puerto 22 y 80 tanto en pv4 como en pv6. Ya no sé qué hacer. Alguien tiene alguna idea?
Lo único que he hecho es:
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
sudo ufw status
Pero no sé si tiene algo que ver.
Gracias  y saludos
